# Python Pandas -- how to select minimum amount of columns that contain 1s in all their columns across a set of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selection

Given a document-term pandas Dataframe. Where each cell is represented by an occurrence matrix.

```
           clover  seed  sowing  stolon
   1489       1     0       0       0
   1488       1     0       0       0
   9677       0     0       1       0
   9996       1     0       0       1
   0557       0     1       0       0
   0564       1     0       0       0
   0958       0     1       1       0
   1272       1     0       0       0
   1965       1     1       1       1
   4326       1     1       1       0
   4531       1     1       1       0
   6026       0     0       1       0
   6030       0     1       0       0
```

With respect to the first column 'clover' reduce the DataFrame to minimum of 3 rows that contain 1s in all their columns. In the current example clover, seed, sowing contain 1s for 3 rows 1965, 4326, 4531. The results would be:

```
           clover  seed  sowing  stolon
   1272       1     0       0       0
   1965       1     1       1       1
   4326       1     1       1       0
   4531       1     1       1       0
```

Drop the irrelevant column:

```
           clover  seed  sowing
   1272       1     0       0 
   1965       1     1       1
   4326       1     1       1
   4531       1     1       1
```

With respect to any number of columns how can I perform this selection process in an efficient way.

Comment: please post the desired df

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
relevant = ['clover', 'seed', 'sowing']
df[df[relevant].all(1)][relevant]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `df.sum(axis=1)>=3` as a mask. Chain `drop` to this:

```
>>> df[df.sum(axis=1)>=3].drop('stolon', axis=1)
      clover  seed  sowing
1965       1     1       1
4326       1     1       1
4531       1     1       1
```

To make this more general: for `n` columns replace `3` with `n`. You can drop more than one column by passing in a list e.g. `drop(['stolon','seed'])`